# Django: catch database integrityerror

Tags: django

I have a model with a unique field - something like:

```
class UniquePerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
...
```

The user can submit new persons; if the name already exists we should just return an error message - i.e. a view like this:

```
def add_person(request, name):
    try:
       person = UniquePerson.objects.create(name = name)
       return HttpResponse(f"New person with name: {name} added")
    except ?????
       return HttpResponse(f"Error: person with name: {name} already registered in DB")
```

But - I can not seem to catch the `IntegrityError` from the database when I try to add a name which already exists in the database? What is the idiomatic way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You may have imported it incorrectly
To catch a duplicate of a unique model being created use:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

def add_person(request, name):
    try:
       person = UniquePerson.objects.create(name = name)
       return HttpResponse("...")
    except IntegrityError as e:
       return HttpResponse(f"Error: {e.__cause__} or {e.message}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you might do this with try/except, you may aswell do it with a simple if else clause:

```
if UniquePerson.objects.filter(name=name).first() is None:
  person = UniquePerson.objects.create(name=name)
  return HttpResponse(f"New person with name: {name} added")
else:
  return HttpResponse(f"Error: person with name: {name} already registered in DB")
```